# How to get image from client clipboard using ImageMagick via command line in Java?

Tags: java, imagemagick, clipboard

I need to get image from client clipboard and save at a location as jpg. 
I am using ImageMagick via commandline in Java for which the command is 
`imconvert.exe clipboard:myimage test.jpg`

This works fine on command prompt, however when I run this in Java as below

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
Process pr = rt.exec("imconvert.exe clipboard:myimage test.jpg");
```

it gives below error

> imconvert.exe: no bitmap on clipboard `myimage' @ error/clipboard.c/ReadCLIPBOARDImage/139

Do I need to access the clipboard the clipboard separately and then execute the command?Someone let me know how can I get the image from client clipboard.

Comment: Simple explanation: As the error message says `no bitmap on clipboard` at the moment you execute the program there is no bitmap content in the clipboard.

Comment: I do a printscreen and then try executing.Still getting the same error.

Comment: When I press the `Prt Scn` key and then execute your code the screenshot is saved as `test.jpg`.

Comment: The screenshot gets saved when executed on command line ,but getting error when executed through Java:(

Comment: Does your code access the clipboard? How do you create a screenshot?